# Open-source OSGi DMT Admin implementation

Tags: osgi

Is there an open-source implementation of OSGi DMT Admin service? [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi_Specification_Implementations) lists two implementations, neither of which seems to be open-source, but maybe it is missing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is an open source implementation of the DMT Admin spec. BTW, it has been updated to version 2.0 in the forthcoming Residential 4.3 and Compendium 4.3 specs.